# Spark SQL running sum with over() function - summing an indicator

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data:

```
df = [{"Category": 'A', "date": '01/01/2022', "Indictor": 1},
        {"Category": 'A', "date": '02/01/2022', "Indictor": 0},
        {"Category": 'A', "date": '03/01/2022', "Indictor": 1},
        {"Category": 'A', "date": '04/01/2022', "Indictor": 1},
        {"Category": 'A', "date": '05/01/2022', "Indictor": 1},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '01/01/2022', "Indictor": 0},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '02/01/2022', "Indictor": 1},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '03/01/2022', "Indictor": 1},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '04/01/2022', "Indictor": 0},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '05/01/2022', "Indictor": 0},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '06/01/2022', "Indictor": 1}]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

I want to use a LEAD() function to group by 'Category' and then order by 'date' ascending. Then create a new field called 'consec_ind' which is a counter of the number of consecutive days that the indicator has been 1.

This is the code I have tried but it doesn't quite work.

`df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')`

```
%sql
select date, Indictor,
 case when Indictor > 0 THEN 
 (sum(count(Indictor)) over (order by date)) else 0 end as running_total
from df
WHERE Category = 'A'
group by date, Indictor
order by date, Indictor;
```

This is what I would like the data to look like:

```
        {"Category": 'A', "date": '02/01/2022', "Indictor": 0,"consec_ind":0},
        {"Category": 'A', "date": '03/01/2022', "Indictor": 1,"consec_ind":1},
        {"Category": 'A', "date": '04/01/2022', "Indictor": 1,"consec_ind":2},
        {"Category": 'A', "date": '05/01/2022', "Indictor": 1,"consec_ind":3},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '01/01/2022', "Indictor": 0,"consec_ind":0},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '02/01/2022', "Indictor": 1,"consec_ind":1},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '03/01/2022', "Indictor": 1,"consec_ind":2},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '04/01/2022', "Indictor": 0,"consec_ind":0},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '05/01/2022', "Indictor": 0,"consec_ind":0},
        {"Category": 'B', "date": '06/01/2022', "Indictor": 1,"consec_ind":1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

First step: Partition by Category

Second step: Try to partition by your custom condition within first partitioning - i am doing it by incrementing counter every time i meet 0 while iterating over first window

Third step: Calcuate sum within final partitions

Here is version in PySpark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = [
    {"Category": "A", "date": "01/01/2022", "Indictor": 1},
    {"Category": "A", "date": "02/01/2022", "Indictor": 0},
    {"Category": "A", "date": "03/01/2022", "Indictor": 1},
    {"Category": "A", "date": "04/01/2022", "Indictor": 1},
    {"Category": "A", "date": "05/01/2022", "Indictor": 1},
    {"Category": "B", "date": "01/01/2022", "Indictor": 0},
    {"Category": "B", "date": "02/01/2022", "Indictor": 1},
    {"Category": "B", "date": "03/01/2022", "Indictor": 1},
    {"Category": "B", "date": "04/01/2022", "Indictor": 0},
    {"Category": "B", "date": "05/01/2022", "Indictor": 0},
    {"Category": "B", "date": "06/01/2022", "Indictor": 1},
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Category").orderBy("date")

df.withColumn(
    "partition_number", F.sum((F.col("Indictor") == 0).cast("int")).over(windowSpec)
).withColumn(
    "part_sum",
    F.sum(F.col("Indictor")).over(
        Window.partitionBy("Category", "partition_number").orderBy("date")
    ),
).drop(
    "partition_number"
).show()
```

and here is sql:

```
select 
  Category, 
  Indictor, 
  date, 
  sum(Indictor) over (
    PARTITION BY Category, 
    partition_number 
    ORDER BY 
      date
  ) as part_sum 
from 
  (
    select 
      *, 
      sum(
        case when Indictor == 0 then 1 else 0 end
      ) over (
        PARTITION BY Category 
        ORDER BY 
          date
      ) as partition_number 
    from 
      df
  )
```

Output is:

```
+--------+--------+----------+--------+
|Category|Indictor|      date|part_sum|
+--------+--------+----------+--------+
|       A|       1|01/01/2022|       1|
|       A|       0|02/01/2022|       0|
|       A|       1|03/01/2022|       1|
|       A|       1|04/01/2022|       2|
|       A|       1|05/01/2022|       3|
|       B|       0|01/01/2022|       0|
|       B|       1|02/01/2022|       1|
|       B|       1|03/01/2022|       2|
|       B|       0|04/01/2022|       0|
|       B|       0|05/01/2022|       0|
|       B|       1|06/01/2022|       1|
+--------+--------+----------+--------+
```